# How to execute OS paste action via electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm building a clipboard manager application for desktop via `react` and `electron`.

The application will run in the background, and the user can use a specified shortcut to paste the last copied item or open up my application window and select a stored clipboard item and paste it anywhere.

All processes are ready. The copy/store action and also, the selection from stored copied items list and writing it into the clipboard is working fine. But I can't find out how I can execute OS paste action (`Command+V` or `CTRL+V`) via `electron` and paste the clipboard.

I'm struggling to find out how it would be possible to access system actions in `electron`, and I found nothing, unfortunately.

Does anyone know how I can make it happen?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand but there is a [clipboard module](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard)

Comment: @NoGrabbing Yea I know about that. I used it to write the selected into the clipboard.  But actually it doesn't execute the OS paste action which will paste a copy of the clipboard into the destination you want like notepad, IDE or even file into the directory.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use an Electron API to paste, rather than leaving it up to the user to press the paste shortcut themselves?

Comment: @Erick No, not really! But I like to make it happened to paste the clipboard when the user hits the `Enter` key on any clipboard. I have a similar app on my mac and I'm trying to make an application just like it, as my first electron app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [`robotjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs)

```js
const robot = require('robotjs');

robot.keyTap('v', process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'command' : 'control');
```

Comment: I found this today my self, but thank you I mark it as the answer.